# C++ simple dictionary match and insert, unique_ptr, operator<

Tags: c++, trie, overloading

I'm learning C++ and did some reading here and elsewhere on trie structures.  I've written a simple class that performs insert and match using a sorted vector as the underlying container.

I used unique_ptr, but I get nervous using the .get() method to access the raw pointer.  Is there a better way?

Also, I had to overload the operator<, but I'm wondering if there is a better approach than the 3 methods shown.

It would be great to get any other feedback too. Don't be nice. I need conditioning to face ***The Tech Lead***.

Thanks for reading.  George

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

template<class T>
class trie
{
    struct node_t
    {
        T val;
        vector<trie<T>> children;
        explicit node_t(const T&  _val) : val(_val){};
    };

    unique_ptr<node_t> root;

public:

    using iterator_type = typename vector<trie<T>>::iterator;
    using const_iterator_type = typename vector<trie<T>>::const_iterator;

    trie() =  default;
    explicit trie(const T& val): root(make_unique<node_t>(val)) {};

    T& val() const { return root->val; } 

    vector<basic_string<T>>  match(const basic_string<T> & s)
    {
        basic_string<T> prefix;
        node_t const* n = root.get();
        for (typename basic_string<T>::const_iterator s_it = s.cbegin(); s_it < s.cend() ; ++s_it)
        {
            const_iterator_type h_it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it);
            if (h_it != n->children.cend() && !(*s_it < *h_it)) // value exists
            {
                prefix.push_back(*s_it);    
                n = h_it->root.get();
            }
            else
                break;
        }

        vector<basic_string<T>> matches;
        for (const_iterator_type it = n->children.cbegin(); it != n->children.cend(); ++it)
        {
            vector<basic_string<T>> suffixes = get_suffixes(it);    
            transform(suffixes.cbegin(), 
                suffixes.cend(),
                back_inserter(matches), 
                [&prefix](const basic_string<T>& suffix)
                {
                    return prefix + suffix;     
                });
        }
        return matches;
    }

    pair<const_iterator_type,bool>  insert(basic_string<T> const & s)
    {
        if (s.empty()) return(make_pair(vector<trie<T>>().cend(),false));
        if (!root) root = make_unique<node_t>(s[0]);
        node_t * n = root.get();

        typename basic_string<T>::const_iterator s_it ;
        typename vector<trie<T>>::const_iterator it;
        for (s_it = s.begin(); s_it < s.end(); ++s_it)
        {

            it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it);
            if (it != n->children.cend() && !(*s_it < *it))
                n = it->root.get();
            else break;
        }

        if (s_it == s.end()) return make_pair(it,false);

        for (;s_it < s.end(); ++s_it)
        {
            n->children.emplace_back(*s_it);
            sort(n->children.begin(), n->children.end()); 
            it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it);
            n = it->root.get();
        }
        return make_pair(it, true);
    }

private:


    vector<basic_string<T>> get_suffixes(const_iterator_type it)
    {
        node_t const* n = it->root.get();
        vector<basic_string<T>> suffixes;
        if (n->children.empty()) 
        {
            suffixes.emplace_back(1,n->val);
            return suffixes;
        }

        basic_string<T> s;
        vector<basic_string<T>> temp;

        for (const_iterator_type it = n->children.cbegin(); 
            it != n->children.cend();
            ++it)
        {
            temp = get_suffixes(it);
        }
        for (basic_string<T>& s: temp) s = n->val + s;
        copy(temp.cbegin(), temp.cend(), back_inserter(suffixes));
        return suffixes;
    }
};

template <typename T>
bool operator< (const trie<T>& l, const trie<T>& r) { return l.val() < r.val(); };
template <typename T>
bool operator< (const T& l, const trie<T>& r) { return l < r.val(); };
template <typename T>
bool operator< (const trie<T>& l, const T& r) { return l.val() < r; };

int main()
{


    string s("bard barstool barraster barn barndoor brindille breezy broach");
    stringstream sm(s);
    vector<string> words;
    copy(istream_iterator<string>(sm), istream_iterator<string>(), back_inserter(words));

    cout << words.back() << endl;
    trie<char> t;
    for (string const& w: words) t.insert(w);
    for (string const& w: t.match("bar")) cout << w << endl;
    for (string const& w: t.match("br")) cout << w << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*bug:*

Trie implementations need to mark word endings somehow. e.g. If you add the word "bar" to end of the input string, it won't be inserted in the trie (because the trie already contains the whole word as a prefix of other words, e.g. "barndoor"). We can't tell that the word "bar" is there as a separate word because the last letter isn't a leaf node.

To mark the end of a word we need to either insert a special character that will always end up in a leaf node (e.g. '\0' or '~'), or add a boolean variable to `node_t`. (Using a special character may be more efficient, but obviously means we can't store strings containing that character).

---

*fun(?) fact:*

If you reduce the input to just "bard", it will be printed by both of your `match` loops:

```
for (string const& w: t.match("bar")) cout << w << endl;
for (string const& w: t.match("br")) cout << w << endl;
```

That seems incorrect.

---

I'm not sure if it's causing the above issue, but this looks suspicious:

```
    basic_string<T> s;
    vector<basic_string<T>> temp;

    for (const_iterator_type it = n->children.cbegin(); 
        it != n->children.cend();
        ++it)
    {
        temp = get_suffixes(it);
    }
    for (basic_string<T>& s: temp) s = n->val + s;
```

We overwrite `temp` for each child, then only use the last value of `temp` after the loop.

---

```
trie() =  default;
...

vector<basic_string<T>>  match(const basic_string<T> & s)
{
    basic_string<T> prefix;
    node_t const* n = root.get();
...
```

`root.get()` will return `nullptr` for a default constructed trie (and then our `match` function will dereference it and crash). We could just return an empty vector (no matches) if the root isn't present.

---

missing includes:

- `#include <algorithm>` for `transform`.
- `#include <iterator>` for `istream_iterator`.

---

`using namespace std;`

[don't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice?answertab=votes#tab-top).

---

```
struct node_t
{
    T val;
    vector<trie<T>> children;
    explicit node_t(const T&  _val) : val(_val){};
};
```

I'd definitely expect `children` to be a vector of `node_t`, not a vector of `trie`s.

---

There are several places we can use range-based for loops (and `auto`) to simplify the code, e.g.:

`for (typename basic_string<T>::const_iterator s_it = s.cbegin(); s_it < s.cend() ; ++s_it)`

`for (auto const& s_it : s)`

---

```
    typename vector<trie<T>>::const_iterator it;
    for (s_it = s.begin(); s_it < s.end(); ++s_it)
    {

        it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it);
        if (it != n->children.cend() && !(*s_it < *it))
            n = it->root.get();
        else break;
    }
```

Avoid reusing variables (unless they're expensive resources). In other words, declare `it` inside the loop.

(In this case `it`'s actually used in a return statement outside the loop, but if you fix the bug pointed out above, that should never happen. Also, since we return `false` as the second member of the pair, the user should never access that iterator, so there's no point in returning it.)

---

```
if (!root) root = std::make_unique<node_t>(s[0]);
```

It looks like the root node's `val` is ignored. This could perhaps be clearer in the code (e.g. add a comment and give it a `val` of `0` or some other placeholder, instead of `s[0]`).

---

```
    for (;s_it < s.end(); ++s_it)
    {
        n->children.emplace_back(*s_it);
        sort(n->children.begin(), n->children.end()); 
        it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it);
        n = it->root.get();
    }
```

It would be better to find the insertion point for the new child, and insert it there directly. Then we don't have to sort the entire vector *and* then search it anyway to find our lost child.

---

```
    if (s.empty()) return(make_pair(vector<trie<T>>().cend(),false));
```

We can default-construct an iterator, rather than creating an empty vector to get the end iterator.

With modern C++, we can use list initialization:

```
    return { {}, false };
```

---

Rather than overloading `operator<`, we could create a functor, e.g.:

```
struct node_t_less
{
    bool operator()(T a, node_t const& b) const
    {
        return a < b.val;
    }

    bool operator()(node_t const& a, T b) const
    {
        return a.val < b;
    }

    bool operator()(node_t const& a, node_t const& b) const
    {
        return a.val < b.val;
    }
};
```

and pass it to the algorithms where necessary

```
        auto h_it = lower_bound(n->children.cbegin(), n->children.cend(), *s_it, node_t_less());
```

Comment: That is all awesome thank you much for taking the time, I'll be applying all these, that's my homework.